# Is there any solution for semantic similarity score for organization names?

Tags: python, word-embedding, sentence-similarity

currently we use Multi-lingual Universal Sentence Encoder (MUSE) for similarity score. We have a chatbot system where we can define intents with a list of samples of each intent. Then we compare semantic similarity of user's utterance with each of intent samples to decide if that utterance belongs to any intent.

But I don't know how we can deal with organization names (or any name entities), for example if we have intent ask_info, we want sentences like "Tell me info about Google" or "Tell me info about Samsung" belong to that intent. But if we only put 1 sentence as sample, such as "Tell me info about Google", if user types "Tell me about XXX", the similarity score from MUSE is very low, only around 0.4 ~ 0.5 which cannot pass our threshold. So anyone has idea to deal with this situation? Thank u very much.

Comment: So in your system the *intent* is considered the same for "Tell me info about Google" and "Tell me info about Samsung"? If so, you need to normalize your input sentences using named entity recognition.